# Refactoring a find for children of parent created after a time

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, syntax, find

I am trying to find any comments created after a datetime that were not made by the current user.

At first I did this..

```
current_user.comments.find(:all, :conditions=>["created_at > ? AND user_id != ?",
                            current_user.last_checked_mail, current_user])
```

but the problem here was that because it begins with the user model, its only finding comments exclusively made by that user.

So instead, I began searching for all comments associated with the user, and those comments children so long as their user_id is not the current_user

```
Comment.find(:all, :conditions => ["user_id = ?", current_user]).select { |c|
  c.comments.find(:all, :conditions => ["user_id != ?", current_user])  
}
```

But it seems that still draws every single comment related to the current_user, and not their children.

My Comment Model :

```
belongs_to  :commentable, :polymorphic => true
has_many    :comments, :as => :commentable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a parent relation in your comment model? Use that!

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base

   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "Comment"

   def self.after(date)
     where "created_at > ?", date
   end

   def self.replies_for(comments)
     where :parent_id => comments.map(&:id)
   end

   def self.exclude_user(user_id)
     where "user_id != ?", user_id
   end

 end

 class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :comments

    def new_comments
      comments.after(last_check_mail)
    end

    def new_responses
      Comment.replies_for(new_comments).after(last_check_mail).exclude_user(id)
    end

 end

 current_user.new_responses
```

PS. This is for Rails 3.

Comment: This is a very exciting response. I'm learning quite a few new things here. The only catch is that this doesn't exclude comments made by the OP

Comment: I tried this.. but it doesn't seem to be working `where :commentable_id => comments.map(&:id), :user_id != user.id`

Comment: Because that is not valid syntax for a hash. I've updated the answer a bit. I see that you're using polymorphism. I leave that for you to figure out ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Comment.find(:all, :conditions => ["created_at > ? AND user_id != ?", current_user.last_checked_mail, current_user])
```

Comment: Ah yes, but one more variable is required. The parent comment has to be owned by the current user. In this case, all comments have a commentable_id that is the ID of their parent comment.

Comment: Oh, I see. That wasn't very clear in your question. So you're wanting to only select child comments, which belong to comments which are owned by the user? In that case, it's getting messy, but you might want something like: Comment.find(:all, :joins => :commentable, :conditions => ["created_at > :time AND user_id != :user AND commentable.user_id = :user AND commentable_id is not null", :time => current_user.last_checked_mail, :user => current_user])

Comment: Ah it does get ugly. I was curious if it didn't have to.. I got this `ActiveRecord::EagerLoadPolymorphicError: Can not eagerly load the polymorphic association :commentable` Curious if this is my fault.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Comment.all(:conditions => ["user_id != ? AND parent_id = ? AND created_at > ?",
           current_user.id, current_user.id, current_user.last_checked_mail])
```

Better solution is to create a named_scope on the `Comment` model.

```
class Comment

  named_scope :other_comments, lambda {|u| { :conditions => 
                ["user_id != ? AND parent_id = ? AND created_at > ?",
                  u.id, u.id, u.last_checked_mail ] }}
end
```

Now you can get others comments as:

```
Comment.other_comments(current_user)
```

**Edit 1**
Updated answer based for Polymorphic associations:

```
class Comment
  def self.other_comments(u)
    Comment.all(
      :joins => "JOIN comments A 
                 ON   A.commentable_type = 'User' AND 
                      A.commentable_id = #{u.id} AND 
                      comments.commentable_type = 'Comment' AND 
                      comments.commentable_id = A.id",

      :conditions => ["comments.user_id != ? AND comments.created_at > ?",
             u.id, u.last_checked_mail]
    )
  end
end
```

Now you can get others comments as:

```
Comment.other_comments(current_user)
```

Comment: The parent_id called commentable_id, and that number is only referencing the ID of the comment, where in, I need the ID of the User who made the parent comment. Comments are joined in a polymorphic table. I'll update above.

Comment: Updated the answer take a look.